# List of Google API endpoints call by the SDK

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-sdk

We have previously generated a list of Google's API end-points utilised by the SDK by grepping the source repo. Now that that doesn't seem to be available, has anyone else found a way of obtaining such a list? We need to be able to whitelist these end-points on our corporate firewall/proxy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PART 1**

If your objective is to whitelist URLs for your firewall, the URL `*.googleapis.com` will cover 99% of everything you need. There are only a few endpoints left:

```
bookstore.endpoints.endpoints-portal-demo.cloud.goog
cloudvolumesgcp-api.netapp.com
echo-api.endpoints.endpoints-portal-demo.cloud.goog
elasticsearch-service.gcpmarketplace.elastic.co
gcp.redisenterprise.com
payg-prod.gcpmarketplace.confluent.cloud
prod.cloud.datastax.com
```

**PART 2**

List the Google API endpoints that are `available` for your project with this command:

```
gcloud services list --available --format json | jq -r ".[].config.name"
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/list

Refer to PART 5 for a PowerShell script that produces a similar list.

**PART 3**

Process the `Discovery Document` which provides machine readable information:

[Google API Discovery Service](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis/list)

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis | jq -r ".items[].discoveryRestUrl"
```

Once you have a list of discovery documents, process each document and extract the `rootUrl` key.

```
curl https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1 | jq -r ".rootUrl"
```

**PART 4**

PowerShell script to process the Discovery Document and generate an API endpoint list:

Copy this code to a file named `list_google_apis.ps1`. Run the command as follows:

```
powershell ".\list_google_apis.ps1 | Sort-Object -Unique | Out-File -Encoding ASCII -FilePath apilist.txt"
```

There will be some errors displayed as some of the discovery document URLs result in 404 (NOT FOUND) errors.

```
$url_discovery = "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis"

$params = @{
    Uri = $url_discovery
    ContentType = 'application/json'
}

$r = Invoke-RestMethod @params

foreach($item in $r.items) {
    $url = $item.discoveryRestUrl

    try {
        $p = @{
            Uri = $url
            ContentType = 'application/json'
        }

        $doc = Invoke-RestMethod @p

        $doc.rootUrl
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Failed:" $url -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

PART 5

PowerShell script that I wrote a while back that produces similar output to `gcloud services list`.

Documentation for the API:

https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/list

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    This program displays a list of Google Cloud services

.DESCRIPTION
    Google Service Management allows service producers to publish their services on
    Google Cloud Platform so that they can be discovered and used by service consumers.

.NOTES
    This program requires the Google Cloud SDK CLI is installed and set up.
    https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstarts

.LINK
    PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-5.1
    Google Cloud CLI print-access-token Documentation
    https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/print-access-token
    Google Cloud API Documentation
    https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-management/reference/rest
    https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services
    https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-management/reference/rest/v1/services/list
#>

function Get-AccessToken {
    # Get an OAuth Access Token
    $accessToken=gcloud auth print-access-token

    return $accessToken
}

function Display-ServiceTable {
    Param([array][Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)] $serviceList)

    if ($serviceList.Count -lt 1) {
        Write-Output "No services were found"
        return
    }

    # Display as a table
    $serviceList.serviceConfig | Select name, title | Format-Table -Wrap | more
}

function Get-ServiceList {
    Param([string][Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)] $accessToken)

    # Build the url
    # https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-management/reference/rest/v1/services/list
    $url="https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services"

    # Build the Invoke-RestMethod parameters
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-5.1
    $params = @{
        Headers = @{
            Authorization = "Bearer " + $accessToken
        }
        Method = 'Get'
        ContentType = "application/json"
    }

    # Create an array to store the API output which is an array of services
    $services = @()

    # Google APIs page the output
    $nextPageToken = $null

    do {
        if ($nextPageToken -eq $null)
        {
            $uri = $url
        } else {
            $uri = $url + "?pageToken=$nextPageToken"
        }

        try {
            # Get the list of services
            $output = Invoke-RestMethod @params -Uri $uri
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Error: REST API failed." -ForegroundColor Red
            Write-Host "URL: $url" -ForegroundColor Red
            Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red

            return $services
        }

        # Debug: Display as JSON
        # $output | ConvertTo-Json

        # Append services to list
        $services += $output.services

        $nextPageToken = $output.nextPageToken
    } while ($nextPageToken -ne $null)

    return $services
}

############################################################
# Main Program
############################################################

$accessToken = Get-AccessToken

$serviceList = Get-ServiceList $accessToken

Display-ServiceTable $serviceList
```

[Command-line tool JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: John - that's a very comprehensive and supportive answer. Very useful indeed.